# Google Maps: "This API project is not authorized to use this API."

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Recently I started coding a Google Maps service integration. I went ahead and generated an API Key associated with my business email account on bronze level. When I use the service sans API Key everything works swimmingly.

If I use the API Key parameter, with my API key generated in my developer console I get the error message:

> This API project is not authorized to use this API.

The URL used to access maps is below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins={origin_address}&destinations={destination_addresses}&mode=driving&language=en-US&sensor=false&key={APIKey}
```

How does one get the API Key to be authorized for v3 Maps JavaScript API. I am making the call as a raw post in the ASPX code behind to that address. It seems to me this used to work fine when I first started all this, now today all of the sudden I'm getting this error.

I need this to work since I will also be using places and that service seems to only work with the API Key. I would like to be able to have the key configured once and be done with it.

Answer (score 22):

You'll need to enable each API you want to use.

The maps-javascript-API is one API, the DistanceMatrix-API(Webservice) another.

Go to the developer-console->API's and enable the **Distance Matrix API**

Note: this is only related to the [**DistanceMatrix-Webservice**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix), when you use the [**DistanceMatrix-Service of the Javascript-API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) you don't need to enable this service.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized distance matrix was broken out as it's own API feature.

Comment: In 2016 you again need to activate API keys one by one as described here. My places autocomplete field failed - but only in https - and this was the solution.

Comment: @bebbi by 'here' you mean distance matrix webservice.?

Comment: @candidJ I probably meant going to developer console -> APIs and enable every API you require.